# Dynamic SQL Select Variable Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

First time poster with beginner sql knowledge (so go easy on me)

I have a SQL statement currently that extracts monthly data from a table, im looking to make this extraction dynamic and rolling based on previous month.

### For example - Assuming the date is 01/12/2013

```
Select Month10_Values
,Month11_Values
,Month12_Values
from test_table;
```

I want to replace the the numbers of the fields with a dynamic variable something like this:

```
Select Month[curr_month-2]_Values
,Month[curr_month-1]_Values
,Month[curr_month]_Values
from test_table;
```

Where [curr_month] will have been pre-determined (in this case 12 based on an assumed date of 01/12/2013)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, hopefully I've made some sense.

Thanks

Comment: Generally this has no relation to pl/sql. It's just Oracle SQL .
Pl/sql comes into game when you start writing stored procedure or functions.

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko Dynamic sql is pure Oracle Sql for you ?

Comment: Apologies its within a stored proc that im doing it but yeah understand what your saying.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus no, but as far as pl/sql was mentioned, I assume that tmleafs17 works with oracle.

Comment: I do work with Oracle, apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like that (simplified)

```
declare

currMonth number:=12;
plsql_block VARCHAR2(500);

begin
plsql_block:='Select Month'||currMonth -2||'_Values,
                     Month'||curr_month-1||'_Values,
                     Month'||currMonth||'_Values 
              from test_table';

execute immediate plsql_block;
end
```

If you want to get the result of the dynamic statement, take a look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/PL-SQL/Createdynamicsqlstatementandgettheresult.htm) for example.